# How many compatible linear orders exist on the classical Laver tables?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals, universal-algebra, self-distributivity

Let $A_{n}$ be the unique algebra $(\{1,\dots,2^{n}\},*_{n})$ such that
$x*_{n}1=x+1\mod 2^{n}$ and
$x*_{n}(y*_{n}z)=(x*_{n}y)*_{n}(x*_{n}z)$ for all $x,y,z$. We say that a linear ordering $\preceq$ on $\{1,\dots,2^{n}\}$ is compatible with $A_{n}$ if $y\preceq z\Rightarrow x*_{n}y\preceq x*_{n}z$.

What are some lower bounds and upper bounds of the value $t_{n}$? I am more interested in lower bounds than in upper bounds. Since large cardinals may be used to produce compatible linear orderings on the classical Laver tables, it seems like large cardinals may be used to produce lower bounds on the number of linear orderings on the classical Laver tables.

**Unverified statement:** $(t_{0},\dots,t_{5})=(1, 2, 4, 8, 64, 128)$.

So from a compatible linear ordering $\preceq$ on $A_{n}$, one obtains a compatible linear ordering $\preceq'$ on $A_{n-1}$ defined by
$x\preceq'y$ iff $x+2^{n-1}\preceq y+2^{n-1}$. Furthermore, the mapping $\preceq\mapsto\preceq'$ seems to satisfy a sort of Lagrange's theorem (this observation is also unverified): if $\preceq_{1},\preceq_{2}$ are compatible linear orderings on $A_{n-1}$ then there seems to be an equal number of compatible linear orderings $\preceq$ on $A_{n}$ with $\preceq'=\preceq_{1}$ as there are linear orderings $\preceq$ with $\preceq'=\preceq_{2}.$ Furthermore, it seems like $t_{n}$ is always a power of $2$. However, when studying Laver tables one should be cautious since many patterns that appear in the Laver tables are only temporary.

**Computation:** Producing compatible linear orderings $\preceq$ on $A_{n}$ requires surprisingly little brute force search since to produce a linear ordering $\preceq$, we start off with a compatible linear ordering $\preceq^{-}$ on $A_{n-1}$ and then use evolutionary computation to slowly produce a compatible linear ordering $\preceq$ on $A_{n}$ with $\preceq^{'}=\preceq^{-}$.

Comment: Here are the conjectured values of $\log_{2}(t_{n})$ for $n\in\{0,...,21\}$. ( 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 16, 28, 73, 84, 219, 399, 1074, 1326, 3621, 6681, 18156, 20869, 55264, 101134, 273169, 337420). To start $t_{0}=1,t_{1}=2$. Let me see if I can prove this conjecture.

Comment: And this conjecture is false.